# environment vs useValue for constants

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Let's say I have a set of links and i want to add them in separate file like this:

```
export const SITE_LINKS = [
   { text: 'About', path: '/about' },
   { text: 'Projects', path: '/projects }
]
```

And i will use them, let's say in 2 places: `header.component.ts` and `footer.component.ts`

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let link of links">
    <a [routeLink]="link.path">{{ link.text }}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What's the preferred method for adding constants in Angular?

I can see 2 ways:

1. adding them in `environment.ts` files

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  siteLinks: SITE_LINKS
};
```

2. add them as dependencies so DI framework will be able to resolve them.

```
const siteLinks = new InjectionToken<string[]>('site links')

providers: [
  { provide: siteLinks: useValue: SITE_LINKS }
]
```

I want to know w/c one is better approach and what situations should i prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 2):

`environment.ts`

- Use this if you're handling constants regarding the important credentials or configurations e.g *API Endpoints, App ID, Keys, and other similars* that will be subject for change in every environment.
- Variables that are about to change when we switch environments e.g `dev, prod, test`
- Looking into the `SITE_LINKS`, i don't think it's right to put it here, regardless of the environment, i think those items from the `SITE_LINKS` will still remain the same

`Providers`

- Yes, you can use this

`Alternative`

- If those `SITE_LINKS` will only be utilized for header and footer and they're inside the /shared folder, I suggest creating `/constants` (or any directory name you wish to name) instead to hold these type of common/constant data and directly import their paths to the designated components they will be utilized

```
/constants
  site-links.constant.ts
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. There are different ways that I want to know which approach is better. I guess I'll choose the direct import approach in this case. Just one question, aren't private data like API keys safe in this manner since those will be included in the build?